django.bootstrap.как соединить views с файлом html при использовании bootstrap
views
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) # Проверяем учетные данные
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)     # Выполняем вход
                return redirect('home')  # Перенаправляем на главную страницу
    return render(request, 'shopapp/login.html', {'form': form})

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>Вход</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid h-custom">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-login-form/draw2.webp"
          class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 offset-xl-1">
        <form>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
            <p class="lead fw-normal mb-0 me-3">Регистрация</p>
            <button  type="button" data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-floating mx-1">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </button>

            <button  type="button" data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-floating mx-1">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>

            <button  type="button" data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-floating mx-1">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="divider d-flex align-items-center my-4">
            <p class="text-center fw-bold mx-3 mb-0">или</p>
          </div>

          <!-- Email input -->
          <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
            <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Email address</label>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input -->
          <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline mb-3">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter password" />
            <label class="form-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <!-- Checkbox -->
            <div class="form-check mb-0">
              <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="" />
              <label class="form-check-label" for="">
                Запомнить меня
              </label>
            </div>
            <a href="#!" class="text-body">Забыли пароль?</a>
          </div>

          <div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
            <button  type="button" data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
              style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">Login</button>
            <p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">Don't have an account? <a href="#!"
                class="link-danger">Register</a></p>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row text-center text-md-start justify-content-between py-4 px-4 px-xl-5 bg-primary">
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-white mb-3 mb-md-0">
      Copyright © 2020. All rights reserved.
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

    <!-- Right -->
    <div>
      <a href="#!" class="text-white me-4">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#!" class="text-white me-4">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#!" class="text-white me-4">
        <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#!" class="text-white">
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Right -->
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

введите сюда код


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Установите bootstrap
Зарегистрируйте его в settings.py
Подлкючите его в шаблоне   {% load bootstrap5 %}, {% bootstrap_css %},
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

pip install django-bootstrap-v5
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'members',
    'bootstrap5',
]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  {% load bootstrap5 %}
  {% bootstrap_css %}
  {% bootstrap_javascript %}
</head>
<body>

